# Having trouble with count controlled for loop

Tags: java

so I'm taking an Intro to Java class and am having a bit of difficulty finishing up my homework.

First, I'm going to paste the homework directions and then I'll post my code so you all can see where I'm struggling and hopefully be able to help me out.

**DIRECTIONS: 
For the first day worked a person earns $1.00 for the entire day.  For the second day worked the person's daily pay is doubled to $2.00.  For the third day worked the person's daily pay is doubled again to $4.00.  For each consecutive day a person works their daily pay is doubled in this way.**

**Write a program that asks a user to enter the number of days they worked and then calculates the pay they earned for each day along with the total pay they earned for all of the days.  The program output should be the pay for each day and the total pay earned for all the days.**

**Input Validation:  Do not let the user enter a number of days that is less than 1.  Use a loop to prompt them to enter another number for the number of days if they enter a number that is less than 1. Make sure and format your output.**

MY CODE:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Homework7Pennies

{

public static void main (String[] args)

 {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
  DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$#0.00");
  double totalPay = 0;
  int totalDays;

  System.out.println("Please enter the number of days you worked: ");
  totalDays = keyboard.nextInt();

  while (totalDays <1)
  {
  System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number of days. ");
  System.out.println("Please enter the number of days you worked: ");
  totalDays = keyboard.nextInt();
  }

  for(int counter = 1; counter <= totalDays; counter++)
  {
  System.out.println("Pay for Day #" + counter + ": " + formatter.format(counter));
  }
  totalPay = totalPay + counter;
  System.out.println("TOTAL PAY FOR " + totalDays + " DAYS: " + formatter.format(totalPay));

   }
}
```

The issues I am having is:
1) I'm not sure how to double the pay without doubling the first days pay as well

2) How would I print the TOTAL PAY just one time? As of right now, whenever I run my program, it'll print it the same number of times as the number of days worked. I only need it to print once.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, if a person works 3 days, they should be payed 1 + 2 + 4 = $7.
What your loop does is to just print out 1, 2 and 3, without doing anything with those values.  At the end of the loop it adds 3 to totalPay (which is 0), since you haven't modified it at all within the loop.

Comment: #1) You need to modify totalPay within the loop so that you add each day's pay to it.
#2) You need to calculate each day's pay correctly, so you get the right amount to add to totalPay in each iteration of the loop.
#3) If you do #1 and #2 correctly, totalPay should not be modified outside the loop.

Comment: As for your second question, just take the ` System.out.println("TOTAL PAY FOR " + totalDays + " DAYS: " + formatter.format(totalPay));
` outside of the for loop. You need to first correct what it does as mentioned above.

Comment: That is correct, David. It should be $7, but that's where I'm stuck and don't know what to do. If I do counter * 2, then that also multiplies the first day by two which makes it incorrect.

Tim, thank you for your input. I've gone ahead and done that and it prints just once as it should now :) having a bit of a brain fart today. I'm going to work on correcting the first issue now.

Comment: @Khovsepa You can have a variable called `todaysPay` for example. This would be concerned with just today's pay, so would start with 1. Each day that goes by, you double it and then you can display it and also add it to your `totalPay`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want to do.I just made small changes in you `for` loop.And putting `totalPay = totalPay + result` inside loop.Hope this will help you.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$#0.00");
        double totalPay = 0;
        double result = 1.00;//for showing per day payment
        int totalDays;

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of days you worked: ");
        totalDays = keyboard.nextInt();

        while (totalDays < 1) {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number of days. ");
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of days you worked: ");
            totalDays = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        for (int counter = 1; counter <= totalDays; counter++) {
            System.out.println("Pay for Day #" + counter + ": " + formatter.format(result));
            totalPay = totalPay + result;//for getting total payment
            result *= 2;//for doubling payment as number of day increase
        }

        System.out.println("TOTAL PAY FOR " + totalDays + " DAYS: " + formatter.format(totalPay));
    }

}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed, Shahrair. Thank you very much!! I know I was really close, but I was having trouble setting up the "math" portion of the calculation.

Comment: @Khovsepa i was stuck too.but then i use extra variable for doubling per dayz payment

Comment: The only part that is confusing me right now (program works perfectly by the way) is result *= 2 is result = result * 2, correct? So, if we enter just 1 day for number of days worked, why is it not multiplying the result by 2 and thus making it $2.00? This is incorrect of course, but I just want to understand the logic behind the programming for sake of personal knowledge.

Comment: @Khovsepa exactly `result*=2` means `result=result*2`. For 1 day i couldn't put the logic.if you need i will do so.And for first iteration i use result initial value not user input.If you want 1 day pay 2 then take the from user input.

Comment: Ah, ok. Now it makes sense :) For the first days pay we are using a pre-defined value for result which is 1 which was defined by us! Thank you very much!

Comment: Anytime.Now its your turn.Take first day salary from user then do following :)